# How to correctly and fully import BetterSqlite3's Database class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some code that uses better-sqlite3 and I am trying to port it to typescript.

Relevant parts of the original javascript code look like this:

```js
import Database from "better-sqlite3";

/**
 * @param {string} filename
 * @return {Database}
 */
function openDb(filename)
{
    let db;
    db = new Database(/* some arguments */);
    // some initialization
    return db;
}
```

After putting the code in a .ts file and adding types, it looks like this:

```js
import Database from "better-sqlite3";

function openDb(filename: string) : Database
{
    let db : Database;
    db = new Database(/* some arguments */);
    // some initialization
    return db;
}
```

I get the error `TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Database' as a type.` for all places in the code where the `Database` symbol is used as a type.

If I use typescript 3.8's `import type`, then the error is reversed: I can use the symbol as a type, but not as a constructor.

Is there **any** way to import this symbol in such a way that it will be known to typescript BOTH as a constructor AND as a type? Is there some magic that will allow me to express in code the natural flow of thought, "I invoke `new Something()` to construct a `Something` and then I return said `Something`", instead of the convoluted flow of thought "I invoke `new Something()` to construct a `SomethingUnderADifferentName` and then I return said `SomethingUnderADifferentName`"?

Comment: For me, this works: `import type {Database} from 'better-sqlite3'; import * as BetterSqlite3 from 'better-sqlite3'; const DatabaseConstructor = BetterSqlite3.default;` followed by `const db: Database = new DatabaseConstructor(...)`. But since two separate imports are used, this is not what you want, right? I suspect this is an issue with the better-sqlite3 type declarations that the project itself would need to fix, but I don't know either what the solution would look like.

Answer (score 5):

This should work in combination with the [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) compiler option:

```
// index.ts

import DatabaseConstructor, {Database} from "better-sqlite3";

function openDb(filename: string): Database {
    let db: Database = new DatabaseConstructor('/tmp/sqlite.db');
    // Some initialization
    return db;
}
```

No errors are returned when processed like this:

```
$ tsc --strict --esModuleInterop index.ts
```

Comment: This explicitly fails the stated requirement: there must be only one name that can be used to specify the variables/arguments/return types and to instantiate the type, just like in every normal strictly typed language with classes.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
import Database, {Database as DbType} from 'better-sqlite3';
function openDb(filename: string) : DbType
{
    let db : Database;
    db = new Database(/* some arguments */);
    // some initialization
    return db;
}
```

Comment: This explicitly fails the stated requirement.